# How to attach event "ondblclick", whose handler in direct assign take "this" as parameter

Tags: javascript, parameters, event-handling, dom-events

`RawClicked` I have old assign method of tr for event like this:

```
<tr ondblclick="RawClicked(this) .......
```

and I want to attach the event in JavaScript code like this, and delete  assigning the event handler in HTML tag `<tr .... >` :

```
var element = document.getElementById("CustomersTable").getElementsByTagName("tr");
AssigningEventHandles(element, "dblclick", RawClicked(this));

function AssigningEventHandles(element, event, handler) {
    if (element.addEventListener) {
        element.addEventListener(event, handler, false);
    }

    else if (element.attachEvent) {
        element.attachEvent("on"+ event, handler);
    }
}


function RawClicked(raw) {
    var rawDoubleClicked = raw.id;
    alert(rawDoubleClicked);
}
```

So how can I pass the parameter `this` to the function in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. In your example `element` is a collection of nodes, not a single element, so you can't add event listeners this way. You may iterate over this collection of nodes or use event delegation and attach event listener to the `<table>`.
2. In this line `AssigningEventHandles(element, "dblclick", RawClicked(this));` RawClicked is executed with `this` bound to the global object. So the argument passed as `handler` to `AssigningEventHandles` is the result of this function, which is void. You should pass the function like this: `AssigningEventHandles(element, "dblclick", RawClicked);` and then use `this.id` instead of `raw.id` in `RawClicked`.

Fixed code:

```
var element = document.getElementById("CustomersTable").getElementsByTagName('tr');
AssigningEventHandles(element, "dblclick", RawClicked);

function AssigningEventHandles(element, event, handler) {
  if( !element.length ){ /* convert to array if it's a single node */
    element = [element];
  }
  for( var i=0; i<element.length; i++){ /* iterate over nodes and attach event listeners */
    if (element[i].addEventListener) {
        element[i].addEventListener(event, handler, false);
    }

    else if (element[i].attachEvent) {
        element[i].attachEvent("on"+ event, handler);
    }
  }
}

function RawClicked() {
/* `this` is bound to the clicked element */
    var rawDoubleClicked = this.id;
    alert(this);
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/WU76d/

Comment: have you tried the jsfiddle link at the end of my post? works for me ;)

Comment: yes i saw it that is why i voted for ur answer actually , although it doesnt work with me :)

Answer (score -1):

In firefox (uses addEvenListener) it seems as the handler is run in the scope of the element so just using "this" in your RawClicked should work as intended

Comment: pawel's answer is definitely better!